# How to concatenate different type of multiple fields in JSON using JQ?

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file with the following format:

```
[
  {
    "A": "A1",
    "B": [
      {
        "B_array": [
          {
            "B_field1": "B1",
            "B_field2": "B2"
          }
        ],
        "C": 10,
        "E": "E1"
      },
      {
        "B_array": [
          {
            "B_field1": "B3",
            "B_field2": "B4"
          }
        ],
        "C": 20,
        "E": "E2"
      }
    ],
    "F": "F1"
  }
 ]
```

From here, what I want to achieve is that combining/concatenating fields so I can get the output like below:

```
["A1" "B1, B2" 10 "E1" "F1"]
["A1" "B3, B4" 20 "E2" "F1"]
```

what I have done so far is:

```
map(.A + (.B[].C|tostring)+.B[].E+(.B[].B_array[] | join(" | ")+.F))
```

But what I am getting is that every possible combination such as:

```
["A1" "B1, B2" 10 "E1" "F1"]
["A1" "B1, B2" 10 "E2" "F1"]
["A1" "B3, B4" 20 "E2" "F1"]
["A1" "B3, B4" 20 "E1" "F1"]
```

How do I use the right jq query to get the result I expected above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want save each object in the top-level list for later use while you are processing each `B` element.

```
$ jq -c '.[] as $top | .[].B[] | [$top.A, (.B_array[] | join(", ")), .C, .E, $top.F]' tmp.json
["A1","B1, B2",10,"E1","F1"]
["A1","B3, B4",20,"E2","F1"]
```

A variable assignment can be seen as a filter that passes its input through unchanged, but provides a name for the given expression. That is, `$top` is `.[]`, except the `.` refers to the input of the assignment filter, not the current input.